# NetBeans 8.2 failed to start tomcat

Tags: tomcat, netbeans-8

Either tomcat 8.5.3 or tomcat 8 embedded in netbean's installation I have this:

Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\tomcat-8.5.34"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\tomcat-8.5.34"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\tomcat-8.5.34\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\tomcat-8.5.34\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\tomcat-8.5.34\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
22-Oct-2018 19:33:25.628 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.34
22-Oct-2018 19:33:25.649 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Sep 4 2018 22:28:22 UTC
22-Oct-2018 19:33:25.649 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.34.0
22-Oct-2018 19:33:25.649 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 7
22-Oct-2018 19:33:25.649 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            6.1
22-Oct-2018 19:33:25.650 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
22-Oct-2018 19:33:25.650 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre
22-Oct-2018 19:33:25.650 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_77-b03
22-Oct-2018 19:33:25.650 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
22-Oct-2018 19:33:25.650 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\tomcat-8.5.34
22-Oct-2018 19:33:25.650 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\tomcat-8.5.34
22-Oct-2018 19:33:25.650 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\tomcat-8.5.34\conf\logging.properties
22-Oct-2018 19:33:25.650 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
22-Oct-2018 19:33:25.650 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1|it-man
22-Oct-2018 19:33:25.650 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
22-Oct-2018 19:33:25.651 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
22-Oct-2018 19:33:25.652 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
22-Oct-2018 19:33:25.652 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\tomcat-8.5.34
22-Oct-2018 19:33:25.652 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\tomcat-8.5.34
22-Oct-2018 19:33:25.652 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\tomcat-8.5.34\temp
22-Oct-2018 19:33:25.652 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.17] using APR version [1.6.3].
22-Oct-2018 19:33:25.652 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
22-Oct-2018 19:33:25.652 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
22-Oct-2018 19:33:26.626 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018]

**22-Oct-2018 19:33:27.244 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
22-Oct-2018 19:33:27.354 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at** 
...
...

Comment: Is it possible that port 8080 is already being used? Run **netstat -aon | findstr 8080** to find out.

Comment: no... I run it and there is nothing...

Comment: hmmmm.... I read that the tomcat can start when we run the startup.bat file that resides in the bin directory... so I run it manually in the command prompt to see if an error appears... and voilà: "Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined"
And I wonder... shouldn't these be defined through the NetBeans like CATALINA_BASE when we add the server?

Comment: NetBeans itself doesn't care about JAVA_HOME or JRE_HOME; it uses either the setting for **netbeans_jdkhome** in file **netbeans.conf**, or what you have specified in the **Tools > Java Platforms** screen. But if you just set **JAVA_HOME** to your JDK installation Tomcat should be fine. (As an unrelated issue I see that you are using a version of the JDK (Update 77) that is over two and a half years old - you might consider getting the most recent update.)